# Bootstrap Selectpicker not showing complete options

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a searchable list of almost 2700 items in bootstrap selectpicker but when I scroll down options it shows only 50 or 60 options in the list and the remaining are empty [Pleae check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR1uS.jpg).
when I search it searches in all 2700 products (it means search is Okay) but options are not completely listed in the dropdown.

I use `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({ maxOptions:2 })` maxOptions but still no luck.

Hope I was able to describe my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. `maxOptions` is used When you set in a multiple select that in this demo we used `maxOptions: 2`  which means its select up to 2 option.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/br1hyof8/

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
  style: 'btn-info',
  size: 4,
  maxOptions: 2
});
```

```css
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu.inner,
.dropdown-menu.open {
  min-height: 100vh !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bootstrap selectpicker</title>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
  <select data-live-search="true" class="selectpicker" multiple>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 128GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SILVER HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 128GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SILVER HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 128GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SILVER HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SILVER HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 128GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SILVER HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 128GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SILVER HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 128GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SILVER HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 128GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SILVER HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SILVER HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 128GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SILVER HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 128GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SILVER HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 128GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SILVER HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 128GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SILVER HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SILVER HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 128GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SILVER HK</option>
    <option>APPLE IPAD PRO 12.9" 2020 256GB - SPACE GREY HK</option>
  </select>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't want to select 2 max options I want to selectpicker to list all the elements in the dropdown currently it is showing only 50 to 60 in the dropdown and the remaining are empty so I want to show all the options in the dropdown in my given image you can see dropdown is empty.

Comment: We have got your point. Please refer to this updated code link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/Luwztnjs/2/